# Reliably assign a row to a user in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have a table with millions of rows:

```
id | info | uid
```

The uid is null by default. I want to select 10 rows and assign them to a uid, but I want to avoid any potential concurrency issues. So I think the only way to do that is to somehow select 10 rows based on certain criteria, lock those rows and then make my changes before unlocking them.

Is there a way to do row-locking in MySQL and PHP? Or is there some other way I can gaurantee that this doesnt happen:

1. user a queries the table where uid is null
2. finds row 1
3. user b queries the table where uid is null
4. finds row 1
5. user a process row and sets it back to null
6. user b process row and sets it back to null

See my problem?

Comment: Search is your friend, possible duplicate of [PHP / MySQL - how to prevent two requests \*Update](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15027067/342740)

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP / MySQL - how to prevent two requests \*Update](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15026825/php-mysql-how-to-prevent-two-requests-update)

Comment: Just want to know, did you solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

What you probably need is [`SELECT ... FOR UPDATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-locking-reads.html).  With this, retrieved rows are locked until a `COMMIT` or a `ROLLBACK` is made.  So you can do something like :

```
START TRANSACTION;

SELECT * FROM yourTable WHERE uid IS NULL FOR UPDATE;

-- UPDATE to whatever you want

COMMIT;
```